# Kitti stereo poses in world coordinate system

Tags: computer-vision, coordinate-systems, stereo-3d, kitti, visual-odometry

I'm currently experimenting with Kitti stereo dataset (http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/eval_odometry.php), the goal is to find a correct matrix that projects pixels to points in world coordinate system.
The problem is that I'm not sure which coordinate system is used in Kitti dataset. The readme file says:

> Each file xx.txt contains a N x 12 table, where N is the number of
> frames of this sequence. Row i represents the i'th pose of the left camera
> coordinate system (i.e., z pointing forwards) via a 3x4 transformation
> matrix. The matrices are stored in row aligned order (the first entries
> correspond to the first row), and take a point in the i'th coordinate
> system and project it into the first (=0th) coordinate system. Hence, the
> translational part (3x1 vector of column 4) corresponds to the pose of the
> left camera coordinate system in the i'th frame with respect to the first
> (=0th) frame.

So as far as I understood this matrix represents a world to camera mapping, therefore I should take the inverse of it to project from camera c.s. to world c.s.?

Another issue is that I need the world coordinate system to be oriented differently: with -z pointing forward and and y upwards.

The current version of my code looks like this:

````
            M = np.reshape(M, (3, 4))
            #convert local to global c.s. (?)
            Rc = M[..., :-1]
            tc = M[..., -1]
            R, t = Rc.T, -Rc.T.dot(tc.reshape(-1   ))
            M[..., :-1] = Rc
            M[..., -1] = tc
            #convert to CG c.s.
            
            M[0, 1] *= -1.0
            M[1, 0] *= -1.0
            M[0, 2] *= -1.0
            M[2, 0] *= -1.0

            M[1, 3]  *= -1
            M[2, 3] *= -1```


However, when I reproject pixels between consecutive left frames, the resulting pixels end up far beyond image boundaries.

The functions I use for reprojection work correctly, if the coordinates are given in world coordinate system.
````